# JSON_Encode add-on

Tags: json, encode

Is there an add-on for JSON_Encode for EE3?

We used one before in our previous EE2.5 version to convert EE channel entries for our mobile site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will meet your needs, but the EE2-compatible JSON plugin by [rsanchez](https://github.com/rsanchez) may work with EE3 using the manual update described at https://github.com/rsanchez/json/issues/58. The person who suggested the change says it worked for them.

**Edit:** FWIW I did as the instructions laid out and was able to output a channel's data in JSON format using EE 3.5.4.